# Java - Sharing a single object in two different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have created a socket program in which I have created two different threads. First thread is trying to accept the incoming socket connections and other thread starts when new socket connection is established. The second thread is checking whether the socket connection is closed or not by using following code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.println("check error");
if(out.checkError())
{
    //connection closed
}
```

Now whenever I try to use the socket for different operation purpose for example getting the list of process running on remote machine the second thread blocks the program and program goes into not responding state. 
I have checked over internet for `synchronized` block but not found any useful information. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

**Edit**
I found that people not understood what I am trying to say here is the workflow.
1. Server will be created which starts an thread which continuously looks for an incoming socket connection. It can be many connection.
2. Once connection established each connection will be stored into `HashMap`. The same socket object is passed to another threads which checks whether connection is closed or not.
3. In meantime if I try to use the same Socket object for different purpose program goes into not responding state.

Comment: You should close your `PrintWriter`.

Comment: You can print some value in between to check where your program is getting stuck.

Comment: I am having swing gui where button stuck for a longer time and then the program goes into not responding state. And I know swing is not thread safe i'll add `SwingWorker` later.

Comment: Your snippet seems not to be the problem. You should post more relevant code.

Comment: Have you considered a different approach? I would generally recommend having only one `Thread` deal with a socket - unless you have a good reason not to, not just premature optimisation. Once a suitable chunk of data is read you can push just the data on to some other worker thread for further processing rather than letting worker threads mess with sockets. This might not be suitable for your scenario, it's not clear from your post, but will often be easier to compartmentalise and debug, so hopefully it could be useful.

Comment: Are you using the same socket returned from `accept()` for all your threads? Please add more code to your question - both the server socket handling, and the thread creation code.